# on line date dimension table for sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am quite old school and for date dimension table with the usual stuff in like date, day of year, week number, month, month name, quarter, year etc I create a static table and every month increase the data in it, using a  SQL agent Job.

I was wondering if there was an online source for this data that sql server could connect into, using say Json or xml?

Comment: Most people pre-fill the static table to a realistic and reasonable date in the future so you don't have have to update it after the initial creation. E.g. if you generate it to the year 3000 (starting from year 1), that's only a table of ~1,000,000 records which is really not a lot. Any reason you couldn't do the same?

Comment: No reason at all. I am just checking that the world has not moved in this sense